# Trouble installing OpenSSL Cocoapod when creating new application (react native)

Tags: react-native

[MacOS Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU8D9.jpg)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Framework build type is static library
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
[Codegen] Found rncore
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `hermes-engine` from `../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes-(https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4sB8.jpg)engine/hermes-engine.podspec`
[Hermes] Using the release tarball from Maven Central
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.72.6)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.72.6)
Installing Flipper (0.182.0)
Installing Flipper-Boost-iOSX (1.76.0.1.11)
Installing Flipper-DoubleConversion (3.2.0.1)
Installing Flipper-Fmt (7.1.7)
Installing Flipper-Folly (2.6.10)
Installing Flipper-Glog (0.5.0.5)
Installing Flipper-PeerTalk (0.0.4)
Installing FlipperKit (0.182.0)
Installing OpenSSL-Universal (1.1.1100)

[!] Error installing OpenSSL-Universal
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/v2/sxj66rb509g4glxqwld1y1gr0000gn/T/d20231027-34266-gfclaa/file.zip https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL/archive/1.1.1100.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.14.1 cocoapods-downloader/2.0'

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
83 83.6M   83 69.5M    0     0   215k      0  0:06:38  0:05:30  0:01:08 2500k
curl: (18) HTTP/2 stream 1 was reset
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.